# Zend Gdata How to retrieve youtube playlist videos & exclude deleted and private from playlist

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api

I use Zend_Gdata_YouTube(); to retrieve playlist from channel, but some of them contain deleted or private videos. when i pass the feed to

```
 new Zend_Paginator(new Lib_Paginator_Adapter_YoutubePlaylist($playlistData[$playlistParam]['feedUrl']));
```

It also counts deleted and private videos, that's why pages with 0 elements appear. How to create query or filter results by privacy/existance?

```
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Lib_Paginator_Adapter_YoutubePlaylist($playlistData[$playlistParam]['feedUrl']));
$videos = $yt->getPlaylistVideoFeed($playlistData[$playlistParam]['feedUrl']);
```

thanks.

update :

```
$username = $this->config->youtube->username;
        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
        $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);

    $playlistData = array();
    $playlistData['uploads'] = array(
        'title' => 'Uploads'
    );
    $playlists = $yt->getPlaylistListFeed($username);
    foreach ($playlists as $playlist) {
        $playlistId = $this->getPlaylistId($playlist->id);
        $playlistData[$playlistId] = array(
            'title' => $playlist->title->text,
            'feedUrl' => $playlist->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl()
        );
    }

    $playlistParam = $this->getRequest()->getParam('playlist');
    if (!$playlistParam) {
        $playlistParam = 'uploads';
    }

    if ($playlistParam != 'uploads') {
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Lib_Paginator_Adapter_YoutubePlaylist($playlistData[$playlistParam]['feedUrl']));
        $videos = $yt->getPlaylistVideoFeed($playlistData[$playlistParam]['feedUrl']);
    } else {
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Lib_Paginator_Adapter_YoutubeUser($username));
        $videos = $yt->getUserUploads($username);
    }

    $data = array();
    foreach ($videos as $video) {
        $thumbnails = $video->getVideoThumbnails();
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $this->getVideoId($video->getVideoWatchPageUrl()),
            'thumb' => $thumbnails[0]['url'],
            'title' => $video->getVideoTitle(),
            'published' => $video->getPublished()->getText(),
            'description' => $video->getVideoDescription()
        );
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking to query based on the existence of [yt:state](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#YouTube_elements_reference), if the state tag exists then the file is restricted for some reason. You may also find some useful info at [ZF gData](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.introduction.html#zend.gdata.introduction.services) and by looking at the code in `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_State`. You haven't included enough of your code for me to offer any more suggestions on how you might adapt you code.

Good Luck!
**[EDIT]**
Best guess would be to add a videoQuery Either in place of or as part of getPlaylistFeed():

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoQuery();
$query->setParam('state', 0);//you may need to query for all of your videos this way.
```

Sorry I can't help more but this api looks like a tangled mess.

Comment: still unclear for me, because it looks like the video count is 5 (play list has 7 (1 deleted and 1 private), but paginator thinks videos count is 7. 
I've updated the question for some additional code.

Comment: That's ok it's unclear to me as well. I'm not sure if you can build a video query and exclude if yt:state is set or if you have to exclude those videos in your paginator. Sorry.